# Eclipse Debugger Hitting Comments, Skipping Actual Code

Tags: eclipse, debugging

Using Eclipse Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
Build id: 20150219-0600
Java Web app running in Tomcat v8.0 (Gold Copy)

I've restarted my Eclipse and its debugger numerous times over the course of several days, this has been happening constantly for a few days now, so this is not some random fluke:

In my code, the Eclipse debugger hits Comment lines, and skips some actual code lines. Something tells me the actual code isn't being read for debugging. What could be going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens when you source code is out of sync with class files that are being executed in the VM.

To correct this

1. Do a clean build.
2. Deploy your changes (i.e. make sure the class file you built are copied to the execution environment).
3. Re-start your debug session.  The debug information (including line numbers) in the running class files will now match your source files.

Comment: Yes, Add/Remove Projects and then a clean build worked.